# how do you open a JPanel from a JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing

I have just started programming with Swing, and it isn't too easy... I started out with an encryption program, and I have hit a wall. When I click my JMenuItem, it does not open the JPanel specified. Here is my code. There were no errors that were picked up by Eclipse.

```
/**
 * Copyright 2013
 * 
 * You may edit this code and redistribute it to friends,
 * but you MAY NOT say that this is yours, or sell it for
 * money.
 */

package lakecoding.RAMBIT7;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class RAMBIT7 implements ActionListener {

private JFrame frame;
private JFrame About;
private JFrame License;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                RAMBIT7 window = new RAMBIT7();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public RAMBIT7() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(200, 300); //1024x768, 800x600
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("RAMBIT7 Encryption Software 1.0.0");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(0, 13, 0)); //GridLayout, FlowLayout, GridBagLayout, BorderLayout

    /**
     * 'Encrypt' and 'Decrypt' buttons
     */

    JButton encrypt = new JButton("Encrypt");
    JButton decrypt = new JButton("Decrypt");
    encrypt.addActionListener(this);
    decrypt.addActionListener(this);
    frame.getContentPane().add(encrypt);
    frame.getContentPane().add(decrypt);

    /**
     * JMenuBar
     */

    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
    JMenuItem license = new JMenuItem("License");
    JMenuItem close = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    file.add(close);
    help.add(about);
    help.add(license);
    bar.add(file);
    bar.add(help);
    about.addActionListener(this);
    license.addActionListener(this);
    close.addActionListener(this);
    frame.setJMenuBar(bar);

}

public void intializeAbout() {
    About = new JFrame();
    About.setSize(200, 200);
    About.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    About.setTitle("About");
    About.setResizable(false);
    About.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}

public void intializeLicense() {
    License = new JFrame();
    License.setSize(200, 200);
    License.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    License.setTitle("License");
    License.setResizable(false);
    License.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String a = e.getActionCommand();
    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("encrypt")) {
        System.out.println("Begin RAMBIT7 encryption.");
        //encryptRAMBIT7(input);
    } else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("decrypt")) {
        System.out.println("Begin RAMBIT7 decryption.");
        //decryptRAMBIT7(input);
    } else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("about")) {
        intializeAbout();
    } else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("license")) {
        intializeLicense();
    } else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
        System.out.println("Terminating...");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: What is it _supposed_ to do? I see a few JMenuItems being created and added to the pane. No listener or `Action`is added to the JMenuItems. Do you want them to pop up some frame?

Comment: Learn and follow standard Java naming conventions. Any example you find in a book or tutorial will use the guidelines so don't make up your own. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Also for an "About" window you should use a `modal JDialog`, not a JFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you create menu with **new JFrame** initialization,  for example in method *initializeAbout*  you create About Frame , but you don' t show it, try to add *About.setVisible(true)* it must help you.

If you want to add this to existing frame use **JPanel** class instead of frames, and add it to your parent container.

Answer (score 0):

you miss these two lines..

```
About.setVisible(true);
License.setVisible(true);
```

then you got